# hibernate 5, foreign key as primary key, unidirectional one to one

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entities:

First entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "first")
public class First {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    // other properties
    // getters & setters

}
```

Second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "second")
public class Second {

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_id")
    private First first;

    // other properties
    // getters & setters

}
```

I want to make first field in Second entity will be primary key.

```
First first = new First()
repository.save(first);
```

(first.id = 1) must be

```
Second second = new Second()
second.setFirst(first); // as primary key
repository.save(second);
```

(second.first = first) must be

Comment: in your `Second` entity, you have a dedicated ID column. If your foreign key is also your primary key, then you have a design issue. Maybe are you talking about [`Secondary table`](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/09/18/jpa-secondarytable-annotation-example/)? Not related to JPA but please consider rephrase your question, it's very hard to understand what you want

Comment: Just put `@Id` annotation on the `@OneToOne` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@MapsId` and add an `@Id` field to the second entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "second")
public class Second {

    @Id
    private Long Id;

    @MapsId
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "first_id")
    private First first;

    // other properties
    // getters & setters

}
```

See page 37 from [JPA 2 spec](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1551724262_4e703c8e1d266a0312fbb73938cd9860):

> Case (b): The dependent entity has a single primary key attribute corresponding to the relationship
>   attribute. The primary key attribute is of the same basic type as the primary key of the parent entity. The
>   MapsId annotation applied to the relationship attribute indicates that the primary key is mapped by the
>   relationship attribute.
>
> ```
> @Entity
> public class MedicalHistory {
>    @Id String id; // overriding not allowed
>    ...
>    // default join column name is overridden
>    @MapsId
>    @JoinColumn(name="FK")
>    @OneToOne Person patient;
>    ...
> }
> ```